# Move data from many small drives to one big with LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

Used spaceI have LVM built like this

```
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
vda                          252:0    0   10G  0 disk
└─vda1                       252:1    0   10G  0 part /
vdb                          252:16   0   10G  0 disk
└─pro103-home--files (dm-2)  253:2    0   10G  0 lvm  /home/pro103by
vdc                          252:32   0   50G  0 disk
└─pro103by--sql-mysql (dm-1) 253:1    0   90G  0 lvm  /data
vdd                          252:48   0   30G  0 disk
└─dbbackup-data (dm-0)       253:0    0   30G  0 lvm  /dbbackup
vde                          252:64   0   30G  0 disk
└─pro103by--sql-mysql (dm-1) 253:1    0   90G  0 lvm  /data
vdf                          252:80   0   10G  0 disk
└─pro103by--sql-mysql (dm-1) 253:1    0   90G  0 lvm  /data
vdg                          252:96   0  150G  0 disk
└─vdg1                       252:97   0  150G  0 part
```

Drives included in pro103by-sql volume group

```
lvs -o +devices /dev/pro103by-sql/mysql
  LV    VG           Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert Devices
  mysql pro103by-sql -wi-ao---- 89.99g                                                     /dev/vdc(0)
  mysql pro103by-sql -wi-ao---- 89.99g                                                     /dev/vde(0)
  mysql pro103by-sql -wi-ao---- 89.99g                                                     /dev/vdf(0)
```

Used space

```
pvs -o+pv_used
  PV         VG           Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree   Used
  /dev/vdb   pro103       lvm2 a--u  10.00g   4.00m  9.99g
  /dev/vdc   pro103by-sql lvm2 a--u  50.00g      0  50.00g
  /dev/vdd   dbbackup     lvm2 a--u  30.00g      0  30.00g
  /dev/vde   pro103by-sql lvm2 a--u  30.00g      0  30.00g
  /dev/vdf   pro103by-sql lvm2 a--u  10.00g      0  10.00g
  /dev/vdg1  pro103by-sql lvm2 a--u 150.00g 150.00g     0
```

I need to move data from all threee drives - /dev/vdc /dev/vde /dev/vdf to one much bigger
I know how to move data from one drive to another wit pvmove but not sure if this would work in this case.

Comment: You cannot _merge_ the _contents_ of multiple drives this way. Each volume is logically a separate file system on a separate partition--and you cannot simply _merge_ partition this way, either. The only thing you can do is copy each file and directory from each of the separate drives to the same full/path/to/file on the new and larger volume. The command `cp` has several options to assist in doing that--take a look at it's man page with `man cp`. (Or use `mv` instead of `cp`.)

Comment: @C.M. Considering they are all part of the same VG: already merged, it should be possible to relocate blocks to the empty disk at the LVM level without dealing with the filesystem level by using `pvmove`. It looks like OP just wants confirmation. The answer is always the same: do backups.

Comment: @A.B: That is true. As long as the OP just wants to move each logical partition/volume to a different VG, and not merge them in to one, then a pvmove should be fine. Though, my personal preference is to copy them rather than move them--and then delete the old ones after I am certain there were no errors. (In addition to making backups! -- Too many times I have lost data due to unexpected issues and power outages...)

Comment: @C.M. but there is one LV in one VG (over 4 PV). There's no change of VG here.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: do backups.**

As the sum of the space used on the 3 first PVs (50+30+10=80g) amounts to less space than available on the 4th PV (150g), this is possible.

This isn't a complex task, the (1st and) 2nd example in [`pvmove`](https://manpages.debian.org/lvm2/pvmove.8#EXAMPLES)'s man page is for your case:

> Move all physical extents that are used by simple LVs on the specified
> PV to free physical extents elsewhere in the VG.
>
> ```
> pvmove /dev/sdb1
> ```
>
> Use a specific destination PV when moving physical extents.
>
> ```
> pvmove /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
> ```

So adapted to your case, this can be done in three commands, one at a time:

```
pvmove /dev/vdc /dev/vdg1
pvmove /dev/vde /dev/vdg1
pvmove /dev/vdf /dev/vdg1
```

The [man page also tells](https://manpages.debian.org/lvm2/pvmove.8#DESCRIPTION) that this should not be done in parallel for a single LV. No harm would be done, but all moves wouldn't be complete and would have to be run again:

> More  than one pvmove can run concurrently if they are moving data
> from different source PVs, **but additional pvmoves will ignore  any
> LVs  already  in  the  process  of  being  changed**, so some data might
> not get moved.

This can be done online with the database running (behind the scene, the `pvmove` operation ensures a smooth migration by using temporary mirroring mappings etc. Details in the [man page's notes](https://manpages.debian.org/lvm2/pvmove.8#NOTES).). But if that's not mandatory to keep the service running, better do backups and take the database offline before doing it: this allows to rollback from backups in case of unforeseen problems.

You can then verify that all the data is indeed in the PV `/dev/vdg1` by running one of these commands:

```
pvdisplay --maps
```

or specifically:

```
pvdisplay --maps /dev/vdc
pvdisplay --maps /dev/vde
pvdisplay --maps /dev/vdf
pvdisplay --maps /dev/vdg1
```

which will then show used physical extents only in `/dev/vdg1` (all for `/dev/pro103by-sql/mysql`).

The orthogonal command would be:

```
lvdisplay --maps /dev/pro103by-sql/mysql
```

which will then show that all its logical extents are in `/dev/vdg1`.